libpangox-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
while Running the CPN-tools i encountered this error:
./cpntools: error while loading shared libraries: libpangox-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

It needed some other libraries which i installed but somehow i couldn't find libpangox1.0:i386.
and didn't found a proper solution.
what should i do?
ubuntu 22.04.4

I suspect that the CPN software you installed is not compatible with Ubuntu post 20.04 - libpangox seems to have been dropped with a note in the changelog that it is no longer maintained upstream

had the same issue with libpangox-1.0.so.0 on ubuntu24.
Seems like there is no package available from the canonical repos.
Managed to solve this by manually installing the .deb:
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pangox-compat/libpangox-1.0-0_0.0.2-5.1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libpangox-1.0-0_0.0.2-5.1_amd64.deb


Very bad idea. Read the comment in the original question. Not meant for Ubuntu 22.04
